# I got this error when I was installing Firebase in a project using {npm install firebase} command. What's the issue here?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm

**Output:**

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-currency-format@1.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.11.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.11.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.14.16
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!         peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.14.16
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/react@"^11.5.0" from @mui/material@5.14.16
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.14.16
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.14.16" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/styled@11.11.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.14.16
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!       peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.14.16
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!         @mui/icons-material@"^5.14.16" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/styled-engine@5.14.16
npm ERR!     node_modules/@mui/styled-engine
npm ERR!       @mui/styled-engine@"^5.14.16" from @mui/system@5.14.16
npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/system
npm ERR!         @mui/system@"^5.14.16" from @mui/material@5.14.16
npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!     2 more (@mui/system, the root project)
npm ERR!   16 more (@emotion/use-insertion-effect-with-fallbacks, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-currency-format@1.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-currency-format
npm ERR!   react-currency-format@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^0.14 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-currency-format@1.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-currency-format
npm ERR!     react-currency-format@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-08T20_50_52_755Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-08T20_50_52_755Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried using `npm i firebase` but that does not work either.

Comment: Welcome - this issue does not seem to be about the firebase installation - it seems react has some compatibility issues with your OTHER libraries

Comment: Same  problem coming for installing other npm package also. Can you resolve it

Comment: Your react installation is all out of sync - I would start with a basic react sample app and slowly add source code to it